# get error when trying to use twilio's npm package in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, twilio

I am trying to use the twilio node.js library with my meteor application. I was able to install the package using  `meteor npm install --save twilio`

and it installed correctly. However, when I use `import twilio from 'twilio';` I get this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'crypto'(…)require @ modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:119meteorInstall.node_modules.twilio.lib.webhooks.js @ modules.js?hash=9468cd4…:38774fileEvaluate @ modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191require @ modules-runtime.js?
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this. Seems to be a meteor error.

Comment: can you `npm install crypto`?

Comment: i did try meteor npm install --save crpyto and still got the same error

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when you hit the command `meteor npm install`  it should create a folder name meteor-node-stubs (/node_modules/meteor-node-stubs) in which the dependencies such as crypto etc. is arranged.

I think there is a problem with this folder in your project. My suggestion is to check whether you have this folder.

If you do not have it, you can try to install it by `meteor npm install --save meteor-node-stubs` That should solve your problem if this is the case